# Delete one of data JSON from Database

Tags: php, json, database, laravel-5.3

I want to delete JSON from database but I can't

[image]

My delete function in controller:

```
public function deletephoto($id)
    {
        $product = $this->productRepository->findWithoutFail($id);
        $photo = json_decode($product->photo_list,true);
        $photos = $photo[$id-1];
        unset($photos);
        $product->save();

        Flash::success('Photo deleted successfully.');

        return back();
    }
```

**UPDATE**
Here my edit controller:

```html
public function edit($id)
    {
        $product = $this->productRepository->findWithoutFail($id);
        $store = Store::pluck('name', 'id')->all();
        $photo = json_decode($product->photo_list);
        //dd($photo);
        
        $category = Category::pluck('name','id')->all();
        if (empty($product)) {
            Flash::error('Product not found');

            return redirect(route('products.index'));
        }

        return view('products.edit',compact('product','store','category','photo'));
    }
```

Here my view blade.php. I'm using button to delete it.

```html
@foreach($photo as $pro)
<div style="margin-right:10px" class="form-group col-sm-1">
     <p><img src="{{ env('FRONTEND_URL') . "/img/products/$product->id/$pro->name"}}"  width="100" height="100"/></p>
     <a href="{!! route('products.deletephoto', [$pro->id]) !!}" class='btn btn-default btn-xs' onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">Delete</a>
</div>
@endforeach
```

I clik my button delete but it doesn't work.

**LASTEST UPDATE**

My Delete Function

```html
public function deletephoto($productid,$photoid)
    {
        $product = $this->productRepository->findWithoutFail($productid);
        $photo = json_decode($product->photo_list,true);

        foreach($photo as $key => $value) {
                if($value['id'] == $photoid) { 

                unset($photo[$key]);

                }
        }
        
        
        return back();
    }
```

my view blade.php

```html
@foreach($photo as $pro)
<div style="margin-right:10px" class="form-group col-sm-1">
     <p><img src="{{ env('FRONTEND_URL') . "/img/products/$product->id/$pro->name"}}"  width="100" height="100"/></p>
     <a href="{!! route('products.deletephoto', [$product->id,$pro->id]) !!}" class='btn btn-default btn-xs' onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">Delete</a>
</div>
@endforeach
```

I use that code but it doesnt work too...

Comment: Are you trying to remove a single element from that JSON object array or whole object?

Comment: @jigar shah yeahh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are getting `photo_list` column using `$id` and trying to remove it using the same `$id` that's why it is not working. Suppose `$id` is 23, then you don't have 23 id in your json array of `photo_list`

Now if you want to remove en element you need to have `id` of single a image, using that `id` you can remove like:

To remove key from all array

```
foreach($photo as $key => $value) {
   if($value['id'] == '1') { // assumed 1 to be removed
    unset($photo[$key]);
   }
}
```

if you want to remove whole JSON, you can update that `photo_list` column's value as `NULL`

**EDIT**

please check the below example:

```
$photo ='[{"id": "1","name": "test"},{"id": "2","name": "test"}]';
$photo_obj = json_decode($photo,true); // to get array
$result =[];
foreach($photo_obj as $key => $value) {
    if($value['id'] != '1') { // assumed id = 1 to be removed
        $result[] = $value;
    }
}

print_r(json_encode($result));
```

Comment: You followed first part, please update your code according to EDIT example. Your code works for removing a single key from single array like : `name` .

Comment: but...what i want is removing a single key from all array.....,example : [{"id": "1", "name": "bunga4.jpg"}, {"id": "2", "name": "bunga5.jpg"}]...,i want to  delete first id....and result to [{"id": "2", "name": "bunga5.jpg"}] but how?can you help me please Jigar Shah ?

Comment: if you paste my code of EDIT, it is having same scenario what you are explaining, just paste in normal php file and test o/p

Answer (score 0):

seems like your function, `findWithoutFail($id)` fail on finding the `$id`.

try dumping the `$product` and `$photo` to see if it really returning the data of the `$id`

Comment: Is not fail...i get the $id.and i get data array from my photo_list column....but i cant remove it....this is make me very Confuse